# how to break from recursion when using for...in loop

Tags: javascript

```
const find = (json) => {
    let result;
      for (const key in json) {
          if(typof json[key] === "number") {
              result = json[key];
              break;
        } else {
        find(json[key])
    }
    return result;
}
```

Above code helps in finding the value of property which has type number, is there a chance I can break the for..in without continuing the recursion till it's end and access the value as I'm trying to do in the above code. Please let me know the ideal way to access particular value in nested JSON and break the loop once it's achieved.

Comment: Given an object:
Are you trying to find all the key names that have a number type?
Or are you trying to find the first key with a number type?
I'm not exactly sure from your code.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @AndreiIonita : I'm trying to find first number inside Object

Comment: @PraveenSaboji - Beware of "first" in this context. Although object properties do have an order (even in `for-in` loops now -- which is relatively new), the order is complex (and there are some edge cases where it isn't defined, like with Proxy objects). You usually don't want to rely on property order.

Comment: Then TJ's answer below should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing recursive functions, there are a few key things:

1. There must always be a termination condition (a property with a number value, if your case)
2. If the function finds the termination condition, it *returns* something indicating that the condition was found (often by returning the value that you're looking for).
3. If the function finds that it should recurse, it calls itself and then checks the result of calling itself in case that recursive call found the termination condition.

   1. If it did, return the value that was returned from the recusive call.
4. If the function neither finds the termination condition nor recurses, return a value indicating that fact.

See comments:

```
const find = (obj) => {
    for (const key in obj) {
        const value = obj[key];
        if (typeof value === "number") {
            // Found one -- return it (this is #2)
            return value;
        } else if (value && typeof value === "object") {
            // Found an object -- recurse (this is #3)
            const result = find(value);
            // Did recursion find a number?
            if (typeof result === "number") {
                // Yes, return it (this is #3.1)
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    // Nothing found, return `undefined` (explicitly or implicitly)
    // This is #4
    // This is explicitly: `return undefined;`
};
```

Note that I changed `json` to `obj`. It clearly isn't JSON (a string).

Live Example:

```js
const find = (obj) => {
    console.log(`Looking in ${JSON.stringify(obj)}`);
    for (const key in obj) {
        const value = obj[key];
        if (typeof value === "number") {
            // Found one -- return it (this is #2)
            console.log(`Found ${value}, returning it`);
            return value;
        } else if (value && typeof value === "object") {
            // Found an object -- recurse (this is #3)
            console.log(`Found object, recursing`);
            const result = find(value);
            // Did recursion find a number?
            if (typeof result === "number") {
                // Yes, return it (this is #3.1)
                console.log(`Recursive call found it`);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    // Nothing found, return `undefined` (explicitly or implicitly)
    // This is #4
    // This is explicitly: `return undefined;`
    console.log(`Didn't find anything`);
};

// Found at the top level:
console.log(find({answer: 42}));

// Found nested
console.log(find({
    s: "string",
    o: {
        n: null,
        o: {
            s: "string",
            answer: 42,
        },
    },
    n: null,
}));

// Not found
console.log(find({}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to organize breakable deep recursion is to use a recursive generator. When we consume it in a `for-of` loop and `break` the loop, all pending recursions will be stopped automatically:

```js
function* values(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Object)
        for (let val of Object.values(obj))
            yield* values(val);
    else
        yield obj;
}

//

obj = {deep: {object: 'hey'}, here: {be: {dragons: ['a', 'b', {see: 42}, 'skip']}}}

for (let val of values(obj))
    if (typeof val === 'number') {
        console.log('Number', val, 'found')
        break
    }
```

The loop can be abstracted away as well:

```
function find(iter, predicate) {
    for (let x of iter)
        if (predicate(x))
            return x
}
```

and then

```
num = find(values(obj), x => typeof x === 'number')
```